# send failed with error 10093 and shutdown failed with error 10093

Tags: sockets

```
class socketClient
{
    private:
    SOCKET ConnectSocket;
    int numBlock;

    public:     
    socketClient()
    {
        WSADATA wsaData;
        numBlock = countObj;
        ++countObj; 
        int iResult;

        // Initialize Winsock

            iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

            if (iResult != 0) 
            {                
                ssPrintf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
                //return 1;
            }

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) 
        {
            ssPrintf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            //freeaddrinfo(result);
            WSACleanup();
            //return 1;
        }
    }

    void sConnect(char* myHost, int myPort)
    {
        int iResult;
        char port[5];
        struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                        *ptr = NULL,
                        hints;
        ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        _itoa_s(myPort,port,5,10);
        iResult = getaddrinfo(myHost, porgt, &hints, &result);

        if ( iResult != 0 ) 
        {
            ssPrintf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
            WSACleanup();
            //return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
        {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        }
    }

    ~socketClient()
    {
        int iResult;
        --countObj;
        iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
        {
            printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            WSACleanup();

            //return 1;
        }

        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }

    int getNumBlock()
    {
        return numBlock;
    }

    int sWrite(std::string str)
    {
        int iResult;
         // Send an string
        iResult = send( ConnectSocket, str.c_str(), str.size(), 256 );
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
        {
            ssPrintf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            //return 1;
        }

        return iResult; //pocet odeslanych bytu
    }
};
```

I am trying to send string to the client model but while running the model, I am getting error as:

- send failed 10093 and
- shutdown failed 10093.

Please do let me know what can I change in this code.

Comment: This is not MATLAB language. I am removing the tag. I would also strongly advise you to read the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and edit your question accordingly if you want better chances to get an answer.

Comment: Error **100093**: means "successful WSAStartup not yet performed." Can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: Did you consider looking up what Winsock error 10093 means?

Answer (score 1):

Socket error 10093 (`WSANOTINITIALIZED`) means either:

1. `WSAStartup()` has not been called, or it failed
2. `WSACleanup()` has been called too many times.

In this case, your code is calling `WSACleanup()` in places it does not belong:

1. `sConnect()` calls `WSACleanup()` if `getaddrinfo()` fails
2. `sWrite()` calls `WSACleanup()` if `send()` fails.
3. `~socketClient()` calls `WSACleanup()` an extra time if `shutdown()` fails.

`WSAStartup()` and `WSACleanup()` must be balanced.  For each **successful** call to `WSAStartup()`, you must call `WSACleanup()` **once and only once**.  In this case, only your destructor should be calling `WSACleanup()`, and only if `WSAStartup()` was successful in the constructor.

Your code also has other errors in it as well.

Try something more like this instead:

```
class socketClient
{
private:
    SOCKET ConnectSocket;
    int numBlock;
    bool WSAInitialized;

    // private to prevent copies

    socketClient(const socketClient&)
        : ConnectSocket(INVALID_SOCKET), WSAInitialized(false)
    {
        numBlock = countObj++;
    }

    socketClient& operator=(const socketClient&)
    {
        return *this;
    }

public:     
    socketClient()
        : ConnectSocket(INVALID_SOCKET), WSAInitialized(false)
    {
        numBlock = countObj++;

        // Initialize Winsock

        WSADATA wsaData;
        int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
        if (iResult != 0) 
        {                
            ssPrintf("WSAStartup() failed: %d\n", iResult);
            return;
        }

        WSAInitialized = true;

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) 
        {
            ssPrintf("socket() failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            return;
        }
    }

    ~socketClient()
    {
        --countObj;

        if (ConnectSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        }

        if (WSAInitialized)
            WSACleanup();
    }

    bool sConnect(char* myHost, int myPort)
    {
        char port[6];
        struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                        hints;

        ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        _itoa_s(myPort, port, 6, 10);

        int iResult = getaddrinfo(myHost, port, &hints, &result);
        if (iResult != 0)
        {
            ssPrintf("getaddrinfo() failed: %d\n", iResult);
            return false;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        if (connect(ConnectSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR) 
        {
            ssPrintf("connect() failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            return false;
        }

        freeaddrinfo(result);
        return true;
    }

    int getNumBlock()
    {
        return numBlock;
    }

    bool sWrite(const std::string &str)
    {
        int iResult;
        const char *ptr = str.c_str();
        int len = str.size();

        // Send an string
        while (len > 0)
        {
            iResult = send( ConnectSocket, ptr, len, 0 );
            if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
            {
                ssPrintf("send() failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                return false;
            }

            ptr += iResult;
            len -= iResult;
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

Since you are coding in C++, you should consider using exceptions and RAII techniques instead, eg:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>

class winsock_error : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    int errorCode;

    winsock_error(const std::string &msg, int error)
        : std::runtime_error(msg), errorCode(error)
    {
    }
};

class wsaInit
{
private:
    void init()
    {
        WSADATA wsaData;
        int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
        if (iResult != 0) 
            throw winsock_error("WSAStartup() failed", iResult);
    }

public:
    wsaInit()
    {
        init();
    }

    wsaInit(const wsaInit &)
    {
        init();
    }

    ~wsaInit()
    {
        WSACleanup();
    }
};

struct socketDeleter
{
    typedef SOCKET pointer;

    void operator()(SOCKET s)
    {
        if (s != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            shutdown(s, SD_BOTH);
            closesocket(s);
        }
    }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<SOCKET, socketDeleter> socket_ptr;
typedef std::unique_ptr<struct addrinfo, decltype(&freeaddrinfo)> addrinfo_ptr;

class socketClient
{
private:
    wsaInit wsa;
    socket_ptr ConnectSocket;
    int numBlock;

public:     
    socketClient()
        : ConnectSocket(INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        numBlock = countObj++;
    }

    socketClient(const socketClient&) = delete;

    socketClient& operator=(const socketClient&) = delete;

    ~socketClient()
    {
        --countObj;
    }

    void sConnect(char* myHost, int myPort)
    {
        char port[6];
        struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                        hints;

        ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        _itoa_s(myPort, port, 6, 10);

        int iResult = getaddrinfo(myHost, port, &hints, &result);
        if (iResult != 0)
            throw winsock_error("getaddrinfo() failed", iResult);

        addrinfo_ptr result_ptr(result, &::freeaddrinfo);

        // Connect to server.
        int errorCode = 0;
        for(struct addrinfo *ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next)
        {
            // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
            socket_ptr sock( socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol) );
            if (sock.get() == INVALID_SOCKET) 
                throw winsock_error("socket() failed", WSAGetLastError());

            if (connect(sock.get(), result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen) != SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                ConnectSocket = std::move(sock);
                return;
            }

            errorCode = WSAGetLastError();
        }

        throw winsock_error("connect() failed", errorCode);
    }

    int getNumBlock()
    {
        return numBlock;
    }

    void sWrite(const std::string &str)
    {
        int iResult;
        const char *ptr = str.c_str();
        int len = str.size();

        // Send an string
        while (len > 0)
        {
            iResult = send(ConnectSocket.get(), ptr, len, 0);
            if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
                throw winsock_error("send() failed", WSAGetLastError());
            ptr += iResult;
            len -= iResult;
        }
    }
};
```